# Как исправить ошибку 'Превышена максимальная глубина рекурсии'

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия

У меня есть код для ЕГЭ. Задания с 19 по 21. Я написал код для этих заданий, но при запуске кода выдает ошибку RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. Я целый день искал ошибку, гуглил в интернете , но ничего не нашел. Знатоки помогите пожалуйста.

```
from functools import lru_cache
def xodi(h):
    a,b = h
    return (a+1,b),(a,b+1),(a*4,b),(a,b*4)

@lru_cache(None)
def game(h):
    a,b = h
    if a + b >= 310:
        return 'W'
    if any(game(m)== 'W' for m in xodi(h)):
        return 'P1'
    if any(game(m)== 'P1' for m in xodi(h)):
        return 'B1'
    if any(game(m)== 'B1' for m in xodi(h)):
        return 'P2'
    if all(game(m)== 'P2' or game(m)== 'P1'  for m in xodi(h)):
        return 'B2'

for s in range(1, 101):
    h = (16, s)
    if game(h) is not (None):
        print(s, game(h))
```

Вот собственно самое задание, прошу именно решить по моему коду, не писать новый.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(2000) # по умолчанию стоит 1000
```

Это увеличивает возможную глубину рекурсии до конкретного значения

Comment: Ну и как собственно мне это поможет?

Comment: При указании рекурсии 10000, то ничего не происходит

Comment: Да? Я копировал ваш код, ставил 2000 и уменя все прекрасно работало. Как это поможет? Мы увеличили допустимый лимит вызовов функции в глубину.

Comment: Вставляйте этот код перед вызовом всех функций(в начале файла)

Comment: Мне кажется если вы используете рекурсию вы понимаете что функция вызывает сама себя много раз из-за чего тратиться память стэка вызовов, поэтому такое поведение и ограничивается. Кстати StackOverflow с английсткого и есть переполнение стэка.